# How to connect vEthernet (DockerNAT) with Ethernet0 interface?

Tags: docker, windows-10, docker-network

I installed Docker on Windows 10 with Hyper-V. And the virtual network interface named vEthernet(DockerNAT) is generated. Below are network interfaces of my Windows 10 computer.

```
> ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter vEthernet (DockerNAT):
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix.:
   Link-local IPv6 Adress . . . . : fe80::a9a7:f59e:48dc:ff5f%14
   IPv4 Address . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.75.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . .  : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . .  :

Ethernet adapter Ethernet0:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix. :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . : fe80::1091:20e7:135a:3e3f%2
   IPv4 Addres.  . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.200.51
   Subnet Mask . . .  . .  . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . : 192.168.200.2
```

The problem is that vEthernet (DockerNAT) not be connected to my external IP of Ethernet0. I try to make vEthernet (DockerNAT) connected to external Ethernet0 with Hyper-v manager. But not working. In the same case of CentOS 7 one command solves this issue.

```
>  ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
        ether 02:42:be:b3:0c:4c  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.200.51  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.200.255
        inet6 fe80::66f:c6c7:d994:e992  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:57:00:09  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 34  bytes 5821 (5.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 58  bytes 7677 (7.4 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I used iptables command of Centos 7 to let docker0 accept packets

```
> iptables -I INPUT 1 -i docker0 -j ACCEPT
```

Is there a similar functional command or process on Windows 10 to configure DockerNAT connection?